# Creating view using a field(checkbox) as Contextual Filter

Tags: 7, views

I have a content type `product`.I want to create a page view of the products. The view should show only those products whose field `featured` (checkbox) is checked.

How do I use Contextual Filters for this ?

If the field was a taxonomy-term ,I would go to `Provide default value -> Taxonomy Term ID from URL.`

But, since the field is a checkbox I am not able to achieve this.

Thank you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this filter you should add the field as a "standard filter" and not contextual filter. In Views UI look for the headline Filter criteria, add your field "featured" and choose what value that has to be set.

Here is a screenshot how the UI looks, it is under filter criteria where you should push add.

[image: Views UI]

Comment: Thank you for the response. I could not get through the standard filter thing. Could you please tell me how to get it.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you Pontus Nilsson. Actually I just forgot to see that and directly went to Contextual Filter which took much of my time. But after sometime I realised that it could be done through Filter Criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I went through to the same issue. The problem, is that when you add a "checkbox" field in your content type, by default, the values of your checkbox are empty.

In order  to be able to use the featured field (checkbox) as a filter in your view, you have first to define the 2 possible values of your checkbox when editing your feature field of the content type. You can put any pair of values you want, yes/no, 1/0, true/false, pretty/ugly...etc

Find attached below 2 images as examples.

[image]

[image]

Hope it will help.